# openishift create application timeout failed, where is the log or error messages?

Tags: timeout, openshift, failed-installation

I added script in .openshift/DEPLOY. When I add application in Openshift online, it take very long time and finally the web responded that the building application process is taking too long, please refresh the page few minutes later. When I reload the page the application is not created. I suppose the application was failed to build.

BUT HOW can I see the error messages? I cannot not see LOG because there is no built application. So anyone knows how to check it?

Thanks.

hosais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long time later, when I re-visit application page (Openshift applicaion list) the application comes out. Therefore, it is performance issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you'll want to try is appending echo statements to your script. These statement outputs should show up in the output from a `git push`.

Also, action hooks (aka your deploy script) should belong in `.openshift/action_hooks/` directory and should have executable permissions (chmod +x deploy.sh). *I've forgotten to do that a number of times myself*. And if you want to check the logs on the gear you can find them at `~/app-root/logs`.

Comment: the issue op describes is when creating an app, not on git push. Git push shows output while create app can fail without meaningful output whatsoever. And app ends up missing so no debug or push possible.